# Invariant Violation: [2365,"RCTView",11,{"position":"absolute","width":"<<Infinity>>","height":4 is not usable as a native method argument

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting below error every time I load a react-native page that used to work. I removed all 100% widths, actually I tried removing all widths without success. Tried removing all styles as well. Updated expo react native to sdk 38 without success. No width is getting divided in the code. Tried removing the external components I list below without success as well.
Anyone has an idea whats wrong?

```
Invariant Violation: [2365,"RCTView",11,{"position":"absolute","width":"<<Infinity>>","height":4,"backgroundColor":4278221567,"bottom":0,"left":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at UserScreenNavigator.native.jsx:76)
    in UserScreenNavigator (at UserScreenNavigator.native.jsx:83)
    in WithRoutesComponent (at AuthBase.jsx:11)
    in WithUser (created by Query)
    in Query (created by Apollo(WithUser))
    in Apollo(WithUser) (created by Query)
    in Query (created by Apollo(Apollo(WithUser)))
    in Apollo(Apollo(WithUser)) (at client-react/index.native.jsx:153)
    in MainScreenNavigator
    in DataRootComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ApolloConsumer (created by withApollo(DataRootComponent))
    in withApollo(DataRootComponent) (created by Main)
    in PageReloader (at access/index.tsx:49)
    in AuthPageReloader (created by Main)
    in ApolloProvider (at App.tsx:50)
    in Provider (at App.tsx:49)
    in I18nextProvider (at i18nModule.native.tsx:15)
    in RCTView (at Root.js:14)
    in Root (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Root) (at Root.jsx:8)
    in Root (at i18nModule.native.tsx:14)
    in I18nProvider (at i18nModule.native.tsx:41)
    in Main (created by AwakeInDevApp)
    in RCTView (created by AwakeInDevApp)
    in AwakeInDevApp (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
    in AppearanceProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
    in RCTView (at react-native-root-siblings/index.js:32)
    in RootSiblingsWrapper (created by PatchedProviderComponent)
    in DevAppContainer (created by PatchedProviderComponent)
    in PatchedProviderComponent (at AppContainer.js:124)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

invariant
    browser.js:38:14
enqueueNativeCall
    MessageQueue.js:307:15
nonPromiseMethodWrapper
    NativeModules.js:139:8
createInstance
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4269:2
completeWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16949:39
completeUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20912:27
performUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20882:29
workLoopSync
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20848:38
performSyncWorkOnRoot
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20456:22
performSyncWorkOnRoot
    [native code]:0
runWithPriority$argument_1
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5703:31
unstable_runWithPriority
    scheduler.development.js:818:23
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5698:21
flushSyncCallbackQueue
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5686:28
scheduleUpdateOnFiber
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19845:30
dispatchAction
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11880:16
dispatchAction
    [native code]:0
<unknown>
    src.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:390678:34
_callTimer
    JSTimers.js:135:14
callTimers
    JSTimers.js:387:16
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:425:19
__guard$argument_0
    MessageQueue.js:112:6
__guard
    MessageQueue.js:373:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:111:4
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0







import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback,useReducer } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  Keyboard
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import { translate } from '@gqlapp/i18n-client-react';
import { required, validate } from '@gqlapp/validation-common-react';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Autocomplete } from 'react-native-dropdown-autocomplete';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Button,
  Textarea,
  Body,
  Thumbnail,
  Tab,
  Tabs,
  TabHeading,
  Text,
  Toast,
  Spinner
} from 'native-base';
import { Row, Col, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input';
import { TextInputMask } from 'react-native-masked-text';
import {
  resolveMaskValues,
  getAmountInMinimalUnit,
  getAmountString,
  createMask,
  generateReceivedSuggestions
} from '@gqlapp/core-common/common';
import RegisterHistoryForm from '@gqlapp/registerhistory-client-react/components/RegisterHistoryForm.native';
import { Table, TableWrapper, Cell, Row as Rowx } from 'react-native-table-component';
import { FormView } from '@gqlapp/look-client-react-native';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
import Modal, { ModalFooter, ModalButton, ModalContent, ModalTitle } from 'react-native-modals';
import {
  calculateCartTotals,
  payCart,
  updateCartItem,
  addItemToCart,
  updateReceivedInput,
  completeSale,
  addVariantItem,
  updateVariantSelection,
  removeItemFromCart
} from './SaleFormCommon';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-checkbox-heaven';
```